# How to solve the error "too many values to unpack (expected 3)" while working in a deep learning model

Tags: python

Hellow Everone I am trying a solve for the given error message. I have wrote a python function:

```py
def get_dataset_partition_tf(ds, trin_split=0.8, 
    val_split=0.1, shuffle=True, shuffle_size=10000):

    ds_size = len(ds)
    assert (train_split + test_split + val_split) == 1
    
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size, seed=12)
    
    train_size = int(train_split*ds_size)
    val_size = ds.skip(val_split_ds_size)
    
    train_ds = ds.take(train_size)
    val_ds  = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
    test_ds = ds.skip(train_size).skip(val_size)

    return train_ds, val_ds ,val_ds, test_ds
```

but after runing the codes in my jupyter note book I am getting a error message which is

```bash
"too many values to unpack (expected 3)"
```

It will be great help if someone provide me the solution along with some comments on it.

I have tried the function which runs . after that I have tried create the 3 variable named, `train_ds`, `val_ds`, `test ds`

the code I wrote is:

```py
train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = get_dataset_partitions_tf(data)
```

and I am getting an error `"too many values to unpack (expected 3)"`

now I am in thhis place to get assistance from experts to solve the issue

Comment: I don't think the tags of tensorflow, deeplearning and CNN are relevant here

Comment: You're returning four values (`return train_ds, val_ds ,val_ds, test_ds`), you're returning `val_ds` twice, just remove the duplicate.

Comment: You always need to include reproducible code and error messages, not just one lines without context. Which line produces this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the full error and the relevant code as well, but the error wording is the key here (too many values to unpack).

```
 train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = get_dataset_partitions_tf(data)
```

Your function get_dataset_partions is returning 4 variables, but you are also saving three

Answer (score 0):

thank you for ask a question on Stack OV.

You define a function that return 4 objects and your requiring only 3 of them.

```py
def get_dataset_partition_tf(ds, trin_split=0.8, 
    val_split=0.1, shuffle=True, shuffle_size=10000):
    
    # Your logic.

    # Your function is returning 4 objects.
    return train_ds, val_ds, val_ds, test_ds
    
# Based on the way that you are calling the function.
# You are "unpacking" only 3 of 4 objects, raising the exception.
train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = get_dataset_partitions_tf(data)
```

Seems to me that you are doing two things:

- 1. The `val_ds` variable is duplicated (possition 2 and possition 3).
- 2. You already required the `vad_ds` duplicated and you are not declare a destination variable.

```py
# Based on 1, you could remove the duplicated variable `val_ds` at the `return` statement:
def get_dataset_partition_tf(ds, trin_split=0.8, 
    val_split=0.1, shuffle=True, shuffle_size=10000):
    
    # Your logic.

    # Your function is returning 3 objects now.
    return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds

# Based on 2, you could add a new variable (`val_ds_duplication`) after call the function.
train_ds, val_ds, val_ds_duplication, test_ds = get_dataset_partitions_tf(data)
```

References:

- https://medium.com/geekculture/python-variable-unpacking-a5d0ed284011.

### Disclaimer:

I have been trying to look on [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html#the-python-language-reference) in order to find any kind of "unpacking" example with functions but I do not apply a deep research, maybe there is an example about unpacking and you could understand what is happening under the hood.